# Unable to extract countries/cities name from text file using geograpy

Tags: python, geograpy

I am trying to extract countries/cities name from text file using geograpy (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geograpy/0.3.7), but It's returning a empty list.
My code is:

```
import geograpy
text = 'I am from Delhi'
places = geograpy.get_place_context(text=text)

print places.cities
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Why it is not extracting cities name?? Is there any way I can resolve it??

Comment: What is the value of `url` that you are passing into get_place_context()?

Comment: I think you have to execute `places = geograpy.get_place_context(url=text)`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721435/unable-to-extract-city-names-from-a-text-using-geograpypython

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about geograpy but, you could try geotext

```
from geotext import GeoText
sentence = "I am from Delhi"
places = GeoText(sentence)
print places.cities
```

['Delhi']

Comment: But it fails to recognize cities typed with lower case.

Answer (score 0):

geograpy need geograpy-nltk. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/61328309/2971377

```
import geograpy
import nltk

nltk.downloader.download('maxent_ne_chunker')
nltk.downloader.download('words')
nltk.downloader.download('treebank')
nltk.downloader.download('maxent_treebank_pos_tagger')
nltk.downloader.download('punkt')

places = geograpy.get_place_context(text='I am from Delhi')
print(places)
```

Ouput:

```
countries=['India', 'United States of America', 'Canada']
regions=[]
cities=['Delhi']
other=[]
```