# Unable to extract city names from a text using geograpy(Python)

Tags: python, geography, geograpy

I am using Python geograpy library to extract city names from a text
Here is my code:-

```
import geograpy

text='I live in Kadawatha'

places = geograpy.get_place_context(text=text)

print(places.country_cities)

OUTPUT:- { }
```

When I extract city names from a URL it works but from a text, it is not possible and also there is another way to do this by using geograpy.extraction but that is not extracting all possible city names so that I want to use above mentioned way to do this. In additionally there is another question([Unable to extract countries/cities name from text file using geograpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109537/unable-to-extract-countries-cities-name-from-text-file-using-geograpy)) related to this but that is also not working.

Comment: have you installed `geograpy-nltk` ?

Comment: @ohlr that was the problem thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for this to work you need to install `geograpy-nltk`

Comment: How is geograpy-nltk installed?

Comment: thx for trying - but no - its a script command installed with geograpy at least with a more recent version see https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3 and the script at https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3/blob/master/geograpy/bin/geograpy-nltk please edit your answer accordingly and I'll upvote

Answer (score 1):

Kadawatha is according to wikipedia not considered a city but a suburb https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2041605. It's not in the list of cities supported by geograpy.

As a committer of geograpy3 to reproduce your issue i added a test to the most recent geograpy3 https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3/blob/master/tests/test_extractor.py:

where:

```py
def testStackOverflow54721435(self):
        '''
        see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721435/unable-to-extract-city-names-from-a-text-using-geograpypython
        '''
        text='I live in Kadawatha a suburb of Colombo  Sri Lanka'
        e=Extractor(text=text)
        e.find_entities()
        print(e.places)
```

returns:

```
['Kadawatha', 'Colombo Sri Lanka']
```